# How to changed indenting of Items in list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an ordered list with headings between items, e.g.:

  Heading 1
  1. item 1
  2. item 2
    Heading 2
  3. item 3
  4. item 4

However, I want Heading 2 to be flush with Heading 1.  This was the code used (the ul tags are necessary due to the style guide I have to follow).

```
<ul>
Heading 1
  <ol>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
Heading 2
    <li>item 3</li>
   <li>item 4</li>
  </ol>

</ul>
```

I can only use html, so any advice would be great

Answer (score 2):

Use two lists and set start number of the second list to 3

```html
Heading 1
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ol>
Heading 2
<ol start="3">
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple, thank you for that change.  I will check to see if this styling is allowed according to the style guide

Comment: Just asked my supervisor, I am not allowed any type of ccs over-rides such as using start.  It must be only html tags.

Comment: start is an HTML attribute, not css, so you're good to go. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_start.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a listitem (`li` tag) then, include additional lists within each tag. For example:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Heading 1
    <ol>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Heading 2
    <ol>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That way you have one unordered list, two list items in it, then ordered list as embedded lists.

Or, if you want to have the numbers from each sublist use the same counter, per your comment, you would create a CSS counter:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: my-sub-list;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li::before {
    counter-increment: my-sub-list;
    content: "" counter(my-sub-list) ". ";
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        Heading 1
        <ol>
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Heading 2
        <ol>
          <li>item 3</li>
          <li>item 4</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

What I've done here is created a counter, `my-sub-list`, and told CSS to use it in each `ol` list item.

Comment: That is what I had before the code I sent, but I am looking for the odered list to continue the order so 1, 2, 3, 4.  Not 1, 2, 1, 2 as your code would output